# Interchanging Double Sums

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I know there are many threads about the interchange of double sums and I probably read all of them by now. There is just one case, I could not find answered.

Consider a double sum $\sum_i^\infty \sum_j^\infty a_ib_j$. In which cases is the following true:

$\sum_i^\infty \sum_j^\infty a_ib_j=\sum_i^\infty a_i\sum_j^\infty b_j$

Applying Fubini-Tonelli Theorem, we could interchange the double sum like this

$\sum_i^\infty \sum_j^\infty a_ib_j=\sum_j^\infty\sum_i^\infty a_ib_j$

*if the Fubini-Tonelli conditions are met* and we could even sum in an arbitrary way.

I am not sure whether this is the same as $\sum_i^\infty \sum_j^\infty a_ib_j=\sum_i^\infty a_i\sum_j^\infty b_j$.

Comment: these notations $$\sum_i^\infty \sum_j^\infty a_ib_j=\sum_i^\infty a_i\sum_j^\infty b_j$$ are equivalent, so they ever are true.

Comment: They are equivalent only for finite sums. I don't think this hold for any infinite ones.

Comment: what is the difference then?

Comment: @EpsilonDelta: you probably mean $\left(\sum_i^\infty a_i \right) \left( \sum_j^\infty b_j \right)$ ? Your notation $\sum_i^\infty a_i\sum_j^\infty b_j$ might be ambiguous.

Comment: @MartinR Yes I do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}a_ib_j$ denote a well defined sum where $a_i,b_j\in\mathbb R$.

If we set $t_i:=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}a_ib_j$ then actually the sum is defined as $\lim_{n\to\infty}s_n$ where $s_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n}t_i$.

Now observe that $t_i=a_i\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}b_j$ for every $i$.

We could also write that $t_i=a_ib$ where $b:=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}b_j$.

Then $s_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_ib=b\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i$ so that $\lim_{n\to\infty}s_n=b\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_i$

Writing $a:=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}a_j$ we end up with: $$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}a_ib_j=\lim_{n\to\infty}s_n=ab=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}a_j\times\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}b_j$$